# Setting actions toggling in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have 3 `QAction`'s in `QToolBar`. The problem is that the slot `setChecked()` doesn't works. What did i wrong? 
Here's the code:

```
actionSetCursorAddDeletePoint = new QAction(MainWindowClass);
actionSetCursorAddDeletePoint->setCheckable(true);

actionSetCursorMovePoint = new QAction(MainWindowClass);
actionSetCursorMovePoint->setCheckable(true);

actionSetCursorSelect = new QAction(MainWindowClass);
actionSetCursorSelect->setCheckable(true);

QObject::connect(actionSetCursorSelect, SIGNAL(changed()), MainRenderAreaUi, SLOT(/*SetMouseAction(SELECT)*/SetMouseActionSelect()));
QObject::connect(actionSetCursorSelect, SIGNAL(changed()), actionSetCursorMovePoint, SLOT(setChecked(true)));
QObject::connect(actionSetCursorSelect, SIGNAL(changed()), actionSetCursorAddDeletePoint, SLOT(setChecked(true)));

QObject::connect(actionSetCursorAddDeletePoint, SIGNAL(changed()), MainRenderAreaUi, SLOT(/*SetMouseAction(PUTDELETE)*/SetMouseActionPutDelete()));
QObject::connect(actionSetCursorAddDeletePoint, SIGNAL(changed()), actionSetCursorSelect, SLOT(setChecked(true)));
QObject::connect(actionSetCursorAddDeletePoint, SIGNAL(changed()), actionSetCursorMovePoint, SLOT(setChecked(true)));

QObject::connect(actionSetCursorMovePoint, SIGNAL(changed()), MainRenderAreaUi, SLOT(/*SetMouseAction(DRAGDROP)*/SetMouseActionDragDrop()));
QObject::connect(actionSetCursorMovePoint, SIGNAL(changed()), actionSetCursorSelect, SLOT(setChecked(true)));
QObject::connect(actionSetCursorMovePoint, SIGNAL(changed()), actionSetCursorAddDeletePoint, SLOT(setChecked(true)));
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt - arguments in signal-slots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435229/qt-arguments-in-signal-slots)

Comment: In short, you can't give SLOT an argument, directly. Qt5 and C++11 can connect to lambda though, add Qt5 tag if you use Qt5...

Comment: @hyde I don't think so. Firstly, because `QAction` must have slot to change `checked` property. Secondly, because I cannot edit `QAction` class to add my own slot.

And how to use this slot then? If i understood doc right it exists to change `checked` prop.

Comment: @hyde or if u know: is there another way to change `checked` property in `QAction`, may be automatic?

Comment: Uh, why would you subclass `QAction`? You don't need to add slot there, you add it to the class where above code is. Or use that lambda.

Comment: Note that you need one extra slot per QAction instance (which makes lambdas very tempting alternative).

Comment: You cannot bind values to arguments in the connect statement (at least not without lambda). Can you explain what you want to achieve? If you want to act on check/uncheck, connect `SIGNAL(triggered(bool))` to `SLOT(setChecked(bool))`. If you want exclusive actions where exactly one is checked, use a QActionGroup.